# Is there a list of experience needed to reach each level for GoW3?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I just reached level 50 and it is suddenly getting pretty tough to level up. I heard somewhere that in GoW 2 level 70 was about halfway to 100, but on GoW 3 it is around level 60.

Is there a list of experience needed to reach each level for GoW3?

Comment: I noticed that it started to get harder as well. But I also noticed that the amount of XP you earn per match has dropped significantly. I believe that they may have patched it to change the amount of XP you earn per match.

Comment: I think this is going to be an ongoing question as I have heard the numbers may be liable to change. I hadn't noticed the drop in experience however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this table [here](http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/835392-Gears-of-War-3-Level-and-Exp-Chart) and [here](http://www.thetechgame.com/Forums/t=2290394/gears-of-war-3-level-and-exp-chart.html). Not sure how legit the numbers are, however I did a bit of Googling and found various sources saying that level 100 is exactly 3,851,750 exp.

```
| Level | Experience |
| 1     |          0 | 
| 2     |      1,000 | 
| 3     |      2,500 | 
| 4     |      4,500 | 
| 5     |      7,000 | 
| 6     |     10,000 | 
| 7     |     13,500 | 
| 8     |     17,500 | 
| 9     |     22,000 | 
| 10    |     27,125 | 
| 11    |     32,875 | 
| 12    |     39,250 | 
| 13    |     46,250 | 
| 14    |     53,875 | 
| 15    |     62,125 | 
| 16    |     71,000 | 
| 17    |     80,500 | 
| 18    |     90,625 | 
| 19    |    101,375 | 
| 20    |    112,875 | 
| 21    |    125,125 | 
| 22    |    138,125 | 
| 23    |    151,875 | 
| 24    |    166,375 | 
| 25    |    181,625 | 
| 26    |    197,625 | 
| 27    |    214,375 | 
| 28    |    231,875 | 
| 29    |    250,125 | 
| 30    |    269,125 | 
| 31    |    288,875 | 
| 32    |    309,375 | 
| 33    |    330,625 | 
| 34    |    352,625 | 
| 35    |    375,375 | 
| 36    |    398,875 | 
| 37    |    423,125 | 
| 38    |    448,125 | 
| 39    |    473,875 | 
| 40    |    500,375 | 
| 41    |    527,625 | 
| 42    |    555,625 | 
| 43    |    584,375 | 
| 44    |    613,875 | 
| 45    |    644,125 | 
| 46    |    675,125 | 
| 47    |    706,875 | 
| 48    |    739,375 | 
| 49    |    772,625 | 
| 50    |    806,750 | 
| 51    |    841,750 | 
| 52    |    877,625 | 
| 53    |    914,375 | 
| 54    |    952,000 | 
| 55    |    990,500 | 
| 56    |  1,029,875 | 
| 57    |  1,070,125 | 
| 58    |  1,111,250 | 
| 59    |  1,153,250 | 
| 60    |  1,196,250 | 
| 61    |  1,240,250 | 
| 62    |  1,285,250 | 
| 63    |  1,331,250 | 
| 64    |  1,378,250 | 
| 65    |  1,426,250 | 
| 66    |  1,475,250 | 
| 67    |  1,525,250 | 
| 68    |  1,576,250 | 
| 69    |  1,628,250 | 
| 70    |  1,681,250 | 
| 71    |  1,735,250 | 
| 72    |  1,790,250 | 
| 73    |  1,846,250 | 
| 74    |  1,903,250 | 
| 75    |  1,961,250 | 
| 76    |  2,020,250 | 
| 77    |  2,080,250 | 
| 78    |  2,141,250 | 
| 79    |  2,203,250 | 
| 80    |  2,266,750 | 
| 81    |  2,331,750 | 
| 82    |  2,398,250 | 
| 83    |  2,466,250 | 
| 84    |  2,535,750 | 
| 85    |  2,606,750 | 
| 86    |  2,679,250 | 
| 87    |  2,753,250 | 
| 88    |  2,828,750 | 
| 89    |  2,905,750 | 
| 90    |  2,984,250 | 
| 91    |  3,064,250 | 
| 92    |  3,145,750 | 
| 93    |  3,228,750 | 
| 94    |  3,313,250 | 
| 95    |  3,399,250 | 
| 96    |  3,486,750 | 
| 97    |  3,575,750 | 
| 98    |  3,666,250 | 
| 99    |  3,758,250 | 
| 100   |  3,851,750 |
```